# Excel - how to change the contents of a cell based on the contents of another?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

The file that I am working on is a project tracking system. One column is used for status (ready, complete, waiting, etc). What I would like to do is have another column for BF/follow up/hold until date, that I would set when an item is put on hold. Then, once that date passes, the status for that item is automatically changed back to ready.

An easy way to do this would be to set a formula to say if the follow up date is blank or in the past, display one value, otherwise display another. However, I use more than just those 2 values for status, which I have a validation set for.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Could you provide a column and sample data layout (maybe a screenprint?) along with what you have tried so far? That way we can assist with your question more effectively.

Comment: Here's a sample row: http://i.imgur.com/7gObYRr.png. What I am trying to accomplish, is once the BF date has passed, the status is automatically changed to ready. It doesn't necessarily need to do this automatically, I could set it up so that it checks every time I click one of the filter buttons at the top.

Answer (score 0):

In order for Excel to remember the status of a task,
so it can restore it after the BF Date has passed, you need to store it. 
(Or provide some other way to determine it,
such as by testing the other dates.) 
If, for example, you put the actual status into Column `F`
(and the BF Date into Column `J`),
you can get the current status with the formula

```
=IF(OR(J2="",J2<TODAY()), F2, "Waiting")
```

in Column `E`.

[image: spreadsheet]